# Questions related to Java polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, modifier

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     new Person().printPerson();
     new Student().printPerson();
  }
}

class Student extends Person{
   private String getInfo(){
      return"Student";
   }
}

class Person{
  private String getInfo(){
    return "Person";
  }

  public void printPerson(){
    System.out.println(getInfo());
  }
}
```

I have some questions related to Student().printPerson() in the second line of the main function.

What I know is that: Java will first try to find the printPerson() in Student class. Since it couldn't find one, it will go to find the printPerson() in the superclass of Student which is Person. Now it executes the Person's printPerson() and here are my questions:

1. The printPerson() invokes another method getInfo(), so which getInfo will Java choose? Could you please explain with details?
2. Please explain how the modifiers of the getInfo() affect the output.

For your reference, If I remembered correctly. If the modifiers of both getInfo() are public, the output will be: Person Student If they are both private, the output will be Person Person

Comment: Try running the code, with the various modifications you are asking about, and see what happens.

Comment: I have actually ran the code. I know what happens but I don't understand why it happens

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my mobile, so forgive me for grammar and typos.

Also disclaimer, I’m not heavy with java implementation so I am giving a generic explanation and I may have a few things incorrect with how java implements.

What happens is because of access level modifiers and restricting scope.

For your person class,

You have your two methods, public print and private getInfo.

You person class can see both the methods.

Your student class you have one method, private getInfo, and you extend the person class.

Because getInfo is private, it is only know to that class and nothing else. Because of this Java will not override the super (person) getInfo with the Student’s getInfo.

Because the method is not be overridden when Student.Print is being called, student.super.print is resolving to the student.super.getInfo method instead of student.getInfo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have another question. I just refered to my textbook which says that if a method is private, the subclass will not inherit it from superclass. For example the getInfo method here. So if we define another getInfo, instead of overriding the getInfo function we are actually defining a new method which have nothing to do with the getInfo in Person right?

Comment: Correct, student.getInfo belongs only to student. No one else but student knows about this method. Not even the parent, person, in this context. Because of this the getInfo method in person is not getting override by the method in student.

Comment: Also I wonder why there's no error when we try to access the Person's getInfo function by new Student().printPerson(). Does this line try to access the person's private method by an instance of a Student class?

Comment: This is going to get a little technical, but I am going to not include memory addresses to keep this simplified. I hope… In a way, when person.print is called, it is always invoking person.getInfo. When you override a method, you are telling that method to go to this method instead. So if you override person.getInfo with student.getInfo, when student.super.getInfo gets called, it will point to student.getInfo to be executed instead of itself.

Comment: I need some time to consume your last comment, and could you please explain what will happen if the modifier of getInfo are both public?

Comment: I do not know if java will infer override without expressly being told to do so, so you may need to add in the @Override modifier. However, let assume that Java is overriding this. I’m this case, Java will override student.super.getInfo with student.getInfo. So when student.super.print() is invoked it will call student.super.getInfo which then points to student.getInfo and “student” is returned back to the call in print().

Comment: No problem, make sure to make this as the answer if you are satisfied.